# jQuery: Override a tag event for a single element

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

So I have this general submit event for all my forms:

```
$(document).on('submit','form',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('You submitted a form!');
    //here I would put a simple ajax form submit
    return false;
}
```

Now I have a special form that should not trigger the above event.
Instead it should only trigger this event:

```
$(document).on('submit','#SpecialForm',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('You submitted the special form!');
    //here I would put a special ajax form submit
    return false;
}
```

How can this be done? If possible without modifying the first event.

Comment: _Not clear what you are asking.._

Comment: A form submit for any form should execute the first callback, unless it has the id "SpecialForm" (in that case the second callback should be called).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've said you **don't** want to modify your first handler, here are a couple of options that avoid doing that:

1. If you register your second handler **before** your first one, you can stop it via

```
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

...because handlers are executed in the order they're attached (this is guaranteed by jQuery, cross-browser) and that stops the execution of any other handlers attached on the same element (`document`).

```js
// Note that this one must be first if they're on
// the same element
$(document).on("click", "#foo", function(e) {
      console.log("foo click");
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      return false;
});
$(document).on("click", "div", function() {
  console.log("main click");
});
```

```html
Click each of the following divs:
<div>main</div>
<div id="foo">foo</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

2.  Or register it on `document.body` rather than `document`, since `document.body` will be between `document` and your form:

```
$(document).on('submit','#SpecialForm',function(e){
```

...and your existing `return false` will prevent propagation from `document.body` to `document`.

```js
// Note that this one must be first if they're on
// the same element
$(document).on("click", "div", function() {
  console.log("main click");
});
$(document.body).on("click", "#foo", function(e) {
      console.log("foo click");
      return false;
});
```

```html
Click each of the following divs:
<div>main</div>
<div id="foo">foo</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm wondering if we could access the internal object that stores the registered events and rearrange the order.

Comment: @Forivin: You might be able to, but not with the API, you'd be playing around with internals and would have to check with each dot release of jQuery that they hadn't changed those internals. But there's no need, both solutions above are robust and within the documented API. The second solution is probably better than the first, since it doesn't rely on the order in which the handlers are attached.

Answer (score 1):

You can detect `event's target` and trigger the appropriate function:

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   if (e.target.id == 'SpecialForm') {
      console.log('You submitted the special form!');
      //here I would put a special ajax form submit
      return false;
   } else {
      console.log('You submitted a form!');
      //here I would put a simple ajax form submit
      return false;
   }
});
```

Comment: *"If possible without modifying the first event."*

Answer (score -1):

You must exclude SpecialForm from others... So your first function shoud be like:

```
$(document).on('submit','form:not(#SpecialForm)',function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
    console.log('You submitted a form!');
    //here I would put a simple ajax form submit
    return false;
}
```

Comment: *"If possible without modifying the first event."*